# How to run prolog queries from within the prolog file in swi-prolog?

Tags: prolog

If I have a prolog file defining the rules, and open it in a prolog terminal in windows, it loads the facts. However, then it shows the `?-` prompt for me to manually type something. How can I add code to the file, so that it will actually evaluate those specific statements as if I typed them in?

something like this

`dog.pl`

```
dog(john).
dog(ben).

% execute this and output this right away when I open it in the console
dog(X).
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

There is an ISO *directive* on this purpose (and more): [initialization](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(initialization)/1)
If you have a file, say dog.pl in a folder, with this content

```
dog(john).
dog(ben).

:- initialization forall(dog(X), writeln(X)).
```

when you consult the file you get

```
?- [dog].
john
ben
true.
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that just asserting `dog(X).` doesn't call `dog(X)` as a query, but rather attempts to assert is as a fact or rule, which it will do and warn about a singleton variable.

Here's a way to cause the execution the way you're describing (this works for SWI Prolog, but not GNU Prolog):

`foo.pl` contents:

```
dog(john).
dog(ben).

% execute this and output this right away when I open it in the console
%  This will write each successful query for dog(X)
:- forall(dog(X), (write(X), nl)).
```

What this does is write out the result of the `dog(X)` query, and then force a backtrack, via the `false` call, back to `dog(X)` which will find the next solution. This continues until there are no more `dog(X)` solutions which ultimately fails. The `; true` ensures that `true` is called when `dog(X)` finally fails so that the entire expression succeeds after writing out all of the successful queries to `dog(X)`.

```
?- [foo].
john
ben
true.
```

You could also encapsulate it in a predicate:

```
start_up :-
    forall(dog(X), (write(X), nl)).

% execute this and output this right away when I open it in the console
:- start_up.
```

If you want to run the query and then exit, you can remove the `:- start_up.` from the file and run it from the command line:

```
$ swipl -l foo.pl -t start_up
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.2.3)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

john
ben
% halt
$
```

Answer (score 3):

dog.pl:

```
dog(john).
dog(ben).

run :- dog(X), write(X).
% OR:
% :- dog(X), write(X).  
% To print only the first option automatically after consulting.
```

Then:

```
$ swipl
1 ?- [dog].
% dog compiled 0.00 sec, 4 clauses
true.

2 ?- run.
john
true ;   # ';' is pressed by the user 
ben
true.

3 ?-
```

Comment: putting `run` prefix didn't output anything, but not putting it only output the first result.