# getting Syntax error: while trying to execute a prolog program from a shell script

Tags: prolog

I am getting a `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` while trying to execute a prolog program from a shell script.
This is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -xv
yap -L test1(pos,1,2))\. >> rules.pl
```

This is the error message:

```
yap -L test1(pos,1,2))\. >> rules.pl
./tp.sh: 3: ./tp.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

`test1(pos,1,2).` runs when I run it directly from yap.

Tried [How to run prolog queries from within the prolog file in swi-prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232140/how-to-run-prolog-queries-from-within-the-prolog-file-in-swi-prolog) this already.

Comment: I can't test this with yap, but I think the error is coming from bash rather than yap. Try: `yap -L "test1(pos, 1, 2)." >> rules.pl` I've found when flagging goals for SWI-Prolog to run from the command line that they need to be in quotation marks when they're anything more than an atom.

Comment: You have an extra `)` in your goal.

Comment: The documentation for `yap` says that the `-L` option is for compiling a prolog file: `yap -L file-name.pl ...`. You're providing a goal, which would be provided with `-g`. You'd need both I think: `yap -L rules.pl -g 'test1(pos,1,2).'` (assuming `rules.pl` is the file containing the `test1` predicate source). If you want to use the procedure described in the link you provided, you would first just run `yap` at the command line, then at the prompt, enter `[rules]` followed by `test1(pos, 1, 2).` (again, assuming your prolog file is `rules.pl`).